# how to set a variable through a function call in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, for-loop

I want to set a variable by running a function and retrieving a value.

This is my code (abbreviated if-checks):

```
var setToPage  = return loopHistory("external");

function loopHistory(scope) {
    for (var i = $.mobile.urlHistory.stack.length-2; i>=0; i--) {

        if (scope == "internal" ){
            if ( some[i] == thing ) || i == 0  ) {
                i == 0 ?  $temp =  "VALUE-ONE" : $temp =  "VALUE-TWO"
                return $temp;
                break;
                }
            } else if (scope == "external") {
                $temp = some[i];
                if ( thing == true )  {
                    return $temp;
                    break;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

This does not work.

**Question**:
How do I declare the value of **setToPage** by running the function above?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Hi Frequent, in the future, please tell us the error message. "It doesn't work" is not very informative. It would be like telling your mechanic that your car is broken without telling him/her what the symptoms are (doesn't start, makes wierd noise, check engine light on, etc) :) You're lucky Marc B has a sharp eye for detail ;)

Comment: @jmort253 he makes it more challenging (and fun) to omit those details though...

Comment: Remove the first `return` on the running of the function, and place a `return` statement outside the `for` loop, right now you're overwriting the `$temp` variable on each iteration, and it does'nt seem to be declared anywere, which would probably make it global aswell?

Comment: @adeneo: I declared $temp inside the function I'm trying to run this snippet in (should have included that I guess)

Comment: @ajax333221 - I can see that. Train hard :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what the point of the `return` on your first line is... return is for inside a function, to return a value to whatever called the function.

```
var setToPage  = loopHistory("external");
```

Comment: you have a point :-) (make that two). And I wrote elseif instead of else if. Let's see if that works.